# One button, changing ID for drawing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I try to make a line graph in Canvas, 
I had a main.html and script in main.js (dosen`t matter what is inside - I will paste only the end of the code).

This is the end of main.js   - plot,plot2,plot3 is a function to draw a line.

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = plot;  ///drawing line 1
document.getElementById("button2").onclick = plot2; //drawing line 2 
document.getElementById("button3").onclick = plot3; //drawing line 3 
document.getElementById("button4").onclick = plot4; //drawing .... 
document.getElementById("button5").onclick = plot5; //drawing ...
```

In main.html i had

```
 <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Rysuj" /></td>
<input type="submit" name="button2" id="button2" value="Rysuj2" /></td>
                   <input type="submit" name="button3" id="button3" value="Rysuj3" /></td>
                   <input type="submit" name="button4" id="button4" value="Rysuj4" /></td>
                   <input type="submit" name="button5" id="button5" value="Rysuj5" /></td>
```

And when I press  buttons Rysuj, Rysuj2, Rysuj3 all are drawing.

But i would like to make just 1 button like a 'Rysuj' and i try to change a ID after click but something dosn`t work.

In main.html I wrote:

```
  <script language="text/javascript">
function something(){
document.getElementById("button").id = "button2"


}
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="something()" value="Rysuj" id="button">
```

What i should do to Make just a 1 Button which after click will change ID to button2, after next click to button3 etc ?

Comment: Is there a reason that you use submit  type button?

Comment: no - small mistake when i copy a line. But i dont think that this is important. I changed now to   <input type="button"  value="Rysuj" id="button"> and still this same, just one line is drawing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about change draw line function of the first button after each click?

```
var arr = ['plot','plot2','plot3','plot4','plot5'];
var count=0;
document.getElementById("button").onclick = something;
function something(){
    eval(arr[count%arr.length]+'();');
    count++;
}
```

Comment: This same, i dont know why, it`s drawing just the 'plot' no reasons for the next 'clicking'

If i good understood all, I have to change just the code(script) in main.html nothing in main.js ?

Comment: Would you remove "document.getElementById("button").onclick = plot;" in main.js

Comment: Now i dont have any lines :)

Comment: My mistake in source.

Answer (score 0):

You can set counter:

```
  <script language="text/javascript">
    var counter = 1;
    function something(){
       document.getElementById("button").id = "button" + counter;
       counter++;
    }
  </script>
```

And try to separate your javascript code and html. Inline js like `onclick` doesn't look like nice code.

Comment: i reaplace my code to you, and still no effects, first line is drawing, and no more - like in my old code. Just the plot is drawing , plot2, plot3 no...

Comment: Can you use JQuery or it's not possible for you?

Comment: Yeap i had on deskopt, and in source : <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>